# RandomForestClassifier .fit fails with Memory Error on ec2 but runs without error locally

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-ec2, scikit-learn

I am fitting a random forest classifier on a pandas dataframe containing a tfidf and other features where dimensions are (42238, 155085). The size is 26GB. When training the model locally, the code runs without error (albeit slowly), however on an ec2 instance with 4x the memory, the training process terminates with Memory Error when memory utilization hits 37%. This was consistent across 6 runtime executions. All things being equal with anaconda 2.7, code and data, why would this process fail on ec2?

I am running the model locally on a 16GB macbook pro. The ec2 instance has 64GB memory.

#### What I have tried

1. n_jobs=1
2. n_estimators=10
3. max_depth=10
4. increase swap space on ec2
5. set max locked memory to unlimited

#### ulimit -a on the ec2 instance.

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 251728
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 251728
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

#### Code

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=None, 
                       max_features=0.2, 
                       min_samples_leaf=1, 
                       min_samples_split=2,
                       n_estimators=10, 
                       n_jobs=-1,
                       verbose=1)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

#### Stack trace

```
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py", line 247, in fit
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1603, in __array__
    return com._values_from_object(self)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 47, in pandas._libs.lib.values_from_object
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4684, in get_values
    return self.values
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4629, in values
    return self._data.as_array(transpose=self._AXIS_REVERSED)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3949, in as_array
    arr = mgr._interleave()
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3960, in _interleave
    result = np.empty(self.shape, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this as a guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-centos-7

The following parameters were adjusted and the model was able to complete training.

`vm.swappiness=70` to encourage use of the swap space

`vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50` to encourage more cache usage by the OS